# Getting unreported exception Exception when trying to call function to playback a .WAV

Tags: java, javasound

I am trying to call the following function, which should reproduce a sound:

```
public static void emitirSonido() throws Exception {

URL url = new URL(
    "http://www.wavsource.com/snds_2014-05-25_4108314609264195/animals/chicken.wav");  //URL

Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
// getAudioInputStream()

AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
    getAudioInputStream( url );

clip.open(ais);
clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {


    public void run() {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ok!");
    }
});
}
```

for that matter I am using a simple function call:

```
emitirSonido();
```

But I keep getting:

```
error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            emitirSonido();
                        ^
```

To be honest I don't know what else to try because if I remove the throws it just gives me like 7 more errors, originally the code is from javasound.info

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Then add a try/catch to whatever calls this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emitirSonido` is declared as throwing an `Exception`...

```
emitirSonido() throws Exception
```

When you call this method, you must either catch it or re-throw it, for example...

```
try {
    emitirSonido()
} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

As a side point, throwing `Exception` is not a really great idea, it's better to provide the actual exceptions that are thrown, as callers might like to pick and choose which ones they handle and which ones they re-throw

Take a closer look at [the Exceptions trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more details

Comment: It worked perfectly, I'll definitely read on the Exceptions, we haven't seen that yet in class but I always like trying to be one step ahead.

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper It's an important core concept, so it would be hugly useful